# Start gunicorn from Python

Tags: python, gunicorn

Is there a way to kick off gunicorn from Python instead of command line? Not with subprocess or anything related to cmd line. Just using Python libraries.

The reason I wanted to run it from Python is that, I have lots of libs and config dirs that are dependent on the path of where the program kick off.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why does that eliminate `subprocess` as an option?

Comment: @jordanm - I tried subprocess Popen gunicorn command. The relative lib path / config dirs it's looking for is exactly the same as if I run from command line out side of a Python script. So it didn't really help

Comment: gunicorn is in Python, so yes, you can run it from within an existing Python rcuntime.  start with `from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import WSGIApplication` and just RTFS.

Comment: @wim - Awesome!!! Would this be a good example that I can follow?http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score -1):

As an example of a project that does what you're looking to do, you can see the airflow start its webserver with gunicorn:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L675

*Update* I admit this concrete example still [uses a subprocess](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L769) but if the config files in directories are your issue you can change your working directory of the process with the `cwd=` argument to `Popen`.
There is [a documented example](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html) of extending the gunicorn `BaseApplication` with a class that loads its own config and then handing off execution to the `run()` method of the subclass, which seems to be the thing you wanted to do over 4 years ago.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is not clear how the link to the file answers the question.